# Multiple Bus Stab Breaker Feeds to Subpanel

Tags: electrical-panel

Edit: All the breakers are 30A capacity. The main panel has 125A main breaker while the Siemens PL subpanel has built in 100A main breaker and 6 pcs 30A GFCI 2-pole breakers. If I use 3pcs 60A breakers for the feeds from main breaker. The current would divide among the 3 pcs, right? The reason most people use mainly one breaker as main feed is because the are no more spaces in the main panel. But if you have spaces, you can make it redundant by using 3 breakers as main feed, right? From an electrical standpoint, nothing wrong with this, isn't it?

[image: 1]

I'll replace 6 of the 16 2-pole branches with 6 GFCIs so there will be 6 blanks in the main panel. Can I use multiple 2-pole breakers (like 3 pairs) to feed the subpanel? This is because I don't know the brand of the main panel, it has 125 Main Breaker (I bought the house second hand). So I don't know the bus stab current rating so to be sure I'll feed three 2-pole feeds to the subpanel (one one bus stab won't overheat). Will this work? Has anyone seen a multiple feed like this?

Also do you see any problem if I'll just put the subpanel in front of the main panel? Any rule regarding this? I can still access the back.

Comment: I'll let the pros give the complete answer. But I do know that you can't simply parallel the feeds - i.e., feed 3 * 'x' to get 3x of current, because (among other reasons) if one feed breaker trips then more load goes on the other 2, overloading the wires & breakers very quickly, etc. But if you want to have each of the 3 feeders feed a *separate* batch of breakers that would be OK (safety-wise) - but I am skeptical that the subpanel would support that type of configuration.

Comment: The Siemens subpanel already has 100A main breaker and each Gfci breaker is 30A. So the 3 feeders in the main panel can even be just without breakers. So can it work theoretically?

Comment: Do you know of any circuit breakers that are not breakers but for continuous connection.. meaning just to connect the bus bar? Because one of the bus stab can take it. So if I use 3, the current would be divided and even better. And avoiding breakers would be better to avoid costs and one of them disconnecting. I know your idea that if you need 100A and you use 30A each lane, and one disconnects, the other two would overload. But in my case, it's for parallel redundancy.

Comment: I don't know enough specifics of breakers/panels/etc. to give you a definite answer. But I do know that if the connectors/wires/lugs/etc. are sized large enough to handle 100A then "extras" make no difference, especially on a short run (i.e., no voltage drop issues) **and** if they are NOT each sized large enough (all components involved) then it isn't safe because you have multiple points of failure *instead of* the desired redundancy.

Comment: Since I don't know the bus stab current rating. I'm estimating it is at least 60A for the 125A main breaker. So my logic is that if I use 3 parallel with total capacity of 180A. No one would heat up because the current will always be divided among the 3. Unless you mean current can only choose one of the path? This occurs if the other breakers trip.Do you know what are those breakers called that don't trip? (except defective ones) If I use 3 pcs 100A. And there a short in the subpanel, and one or two trips, then only one remaining.So better none would trip and only the main breaker would trip.

Comment: In the end, this part of things is theoretical for me - I can handle dealing with light switches & outlets and appliance repairs, but when it comes to panels, I leave that to the pros. So if I were in the same situation, I would rely on what Ed Beal or Harper or Three Phase Eel says. And I think Ed Beal has been pretty clear about not tripling things.

Comment: If i'll go the chair lugs path screwing it to main feeds. Since the subpanel has 100A breaker. Do you know what AWG size must I use to feed the 100A subpanel breaker from the 125A main panel breaker?

Comment: I don't know. Ed Beal or Harper or Three Phase Eel should know.

Answer (score 1):

This would not be legal at all you have 3 breakers in parallel. The proper way would be to install 1 breaker to feed the sub.

Comment: But the 1 breaker may arc since i dont know the bus stab current rating of it. But wont it work.. the current can be distributed in the 3 main breaker feeds??

Comment: As I told you in another post you have a pair of bolts holding the feed from the breaker get a pair of chair lugs , or compression lugs feed the sub I can't tell if it has a main breaker or not so the wire size would need to be the ampacity of the main breaker and the sub panel rating needs to be larger or the ampacity of the main breaker or risk burning everything down.

Comment: Well.. the main problem with the idea is the metal cover.. notice the picture above has the cover on. If I put the chair lugs in the screw.. it is so close to the cover that the person covering it can easily get electrocuted.. and if I won't put the cover.. it's exposed.. that is why the best way is to treat 3 bus stab as lugs. I don't even need the 3 breakers.. just need to connect the 3 as terminals.. get the idea? So if I put 3 70A breakers. It would serve as terminals while the Siemens 12 space subpanel will take care of all circuit breaker job with the subpanel 100A main breaker. Why not?

Comment: In fact I already bough the chair lugs.. here is the picture... https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/1024x768q90/924/HvoHZz.jpg  but worried the cover can hit it more easily. Also I was thinking if I'd use 3 bus stabs, the area would be much more than the chair lugs at main screws. Anyway. For the larger chair lugs in the picture.. the hole is 11mm or 0.433" and the smaller one is size 6mm or 0.236". What is the ampere capacity of each.. what do you think?

Comment: There should be a wire size listed on the lugs. The largest wire size they are listed for would corilate to the capacity on the 90 degree table for the wire type being used.

Comment: I have a chair lug with 2-14 written.. so it can take up AWG 2 as the largest wire, I read AWG 2 has capacity rating 94 A. For my 100A subpanel breaker.. is the 2-14 chair lug with 94A ok? Or should I need larger? I want smallest possible so it can avoid hitting the metal cover.

Comment: I could not tell if your sub had a main breaker. But since you are tapping the buss I would want the wire size to be 125% for safety. If your sub panel has lugs and the number 2 lug for the tap you could use the 90 degree collum that is 130 amp capacity but if going to a breaker you would be limited to the 75 degree table. At this point it would depend on the actual load if the load is not a continuous load you will be fine as the wire only needs to be rated at 100%. Don't forget you will need conduit from the main panel to the sub.

Comment: We don't have any 3-core AWG 2. If you will see the following list https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wire-gauges-d_419.html  7-core AWG 2 (which we have) only has 66A capacity. Is it true?  Why is there no 7-core 100A entry?

Comment: Oh my. I got confused. I thought 3 core means 3 strands.. so the numbers of strands inside a wire for a given size doesn't affect amperage. My subpanel has 100A Siemens main breaker. For 90C insulation. AWG 3 has 110A rating while AWG 4 has 95A rating.. maybe AWG 4 is ok since it's close to 100A? AWG 3 may be too thick.

Comment: This is picture of my Siemens main breaker, https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/800x600q90/921/9eirgU.jpg   what does #4-3/0 mean? why is there a "/0"? So it needs 75 degree table.. I guess AWG 2 at 115A would be perfect. What must be the size of the conduit for AWG 2?

Comment: #4 wire to 3/0. Or  000 AWG the breaker states 75 degree wire on the front.

Answer (score 1):

### NO, no no.

### no.

It's absolutely no good mounting the subpanel stacked on top of the panel, not a safe working setup.

As mentioned in the comments, you can't parallel with multiple breakers that way.

It may be possible to tap the bus of the main panel or the service wires safely to feed the subpanel, but you'd have to be really careful.

Comment: But wont the current subdivide among the 3 main breakers so instead of say 100A of one. It can become 33A each of the 3 making it safer?

Comment: In the picture, the wires are drawn and put in middle. But in actual, all the wires will be at the sides.. what is the possible safe working setup problem with this idea of putting subpanel in front of it when there is a wooden cabinet holding them all?

Comment: From an electrical engineering standpoint, it sounds fine. But picture it this way: If you have a 3-lane highway running smoothly at capacity and one is blocked by an accident. The other 2 lanes are NOT able to take up the excess and in fact are likely to slow down due to the excess traffic. With electricity that means if one feeder trips a breaker (or a wire gets loose or whatever - anything that breaks the circuit) the other 2 are now immediately and dangerously overloaded, overheat, potential fire. *Should* the other 2 breakers then flip quickly: yes. Can we risk it? **no**.

Comment: But the situation is that in normal feed to subpanel. You only use one breaker with say capacity of 100A. So I was using 3 breakers for redundancy just to be sure. Even if one is working, it can be fine.. better if three. What's wrong with this.

Comment: Unfortunately, it just doesn't work that way. Logically it seems like it should. But it doesn't. Harper may be able to explain it better. But the bottom line is that most (I can't say "all", but definitely MOST) things in the NEC are there for very good reasons.